# What does "following" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

This is my sentence
Following UKVI decision to your visa application, please re-submit your original Travel Document.

I've read that "following" can mean "after".
But in this sentence it can also mean "Due to"? Or I'm mistaken. Please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the new required action (resubmitting your travel document) is the next thing to follow the decision.

It's a very common way to begin what is often called 'follow-up' correspondence. If the letter just said "send your travel document" you might wonder why, so they are just restating what has prompted this.